# Wrapper.find not finding class

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

This is my component:

```
const User = ({ users }) => (
  <div className="displayContainer">
    {users &&
     users.length > 0 &&
     users[0].username ?
     <div className="userOnShow">
       <img className="userImage"alt="no image yet"/>
       <div>{users[0].username}, {users[0].age}</div>
     </div>
     :
     <div className="noOneLeft">
      {'Sorry, no new people in your area'}
     </div>
    }
  </div>
)
```

I have 2 questions. what sort of things should I test? i.e. just that it renders certain classes etc?

I'm assuming testing the ternary would be an integration test?

also and my main question, when i do:

```
describe.only('DisplayingUser', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const usersStub = {remainingUsers: []}
  it('expects the props to be correct', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(
      <User
        users={usersStub}
      />
    )
    const userClass = wrapper.find('.userOnShow')
    console.log(userClass, 'uc');
    expect(userClass.length).to.equal(1)
  });
})
```

it fails saying `expected 0 to equal 1`, i.e. it hasn't found my class, but clearly its there?

Comment: IMO - the ternary should be tested in your unit tests, as you can just pass stubbed data, and you want to check your component renders how you are expecting it too. Secondly - your current stub has no users inside of it - so you will not meet the requirements of the first part of the ternary... hence `userClass` being empty. I would also consider naming your tests more explicitly, i.e. ''expects the props to be correct' does not really describe what you are trying to achieve in that test.

Comment: @ajmajmajma ok thanks very helpful. but still, why is the class name not getting found?

Comment: even when I put a fake user in there, it doesn't show...

Comment: ah got it working, hadn't stubbed it properly. any chance I can get some more tips from you? @ajmajmajma do you have an email, contact etc?

Answer (score 4):

I had a same problem, and it is because shallow don't renders the whole component. Rather it renders only 1 level deep.
So for example if we have

```
wrapper = shallow(<Component store={store}/>);
expect(wrapper.find('.foo')).toHaveLength(1);
```

and in the Component we have

```
export class Component {
  render(){
  return(
  <div>
      <div>
           <p className="foo">foo</p>
      </div>
  </div>)}}
```

it wont find the `foo` element because it is in the second div it means it is in the first `dive()`.

To find the class element `.foo` we will need to call:

```
wrapper = shallow(<Component store={store}/>).dive();
```

So remember that basic shallow renders just the first depth, `.dive()` give you one step further `.dive().dive()` gives you two steps (two `div` inside) and so on.
So when you search element be careful in what level that element is contained.