# Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I working on Testcases:

when i am running individual testcases it working fine but altogether if i am running its throwing error for 2 testscenarios.

my tsx code:

```
 const onPasswordChange = useCallback((e) => {
    setStatusAlert({});
    setModel({ ...model, "password": e.target.value });
    setPasswordError(null);
  }, [setStatusAlert, setModel, setPasswordError]);

    const showPasswordInput = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const emailIsEmpty = !model.email || model.email.length < 1;
    setDisplayPasswordInput(!emailIsEmpty);
    setEmailError(emailIsEmpty ? "Email is required" : null);
  }, [model, setDisplayPasswordInput, setEmailError]);
```

My testcases:

```
 describe("onPasswordChange", () => {
    it("sets password to new value", async () => {
      const expectedPassword = lorem.word();
      mockedHttpHelper.get.mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn((params: IGetParams) => params.onGetSuccess({ data: { externalTypes: [] } } as AxiosResponse)));

      await usingMount(
        LoginFormComponent(defaultModelWithEmail),
        async wrapper => {
          await setTimeoutPromise(() => {
            wrapper.find(LoginForm).find("LoginPasswordFormBody").invoke("onPasswordChange")({ target: { name: "password", value: expectedPassword } });

            expect(wrapper.find(LoginForm).find("LoginPasswordFormBody").prop("model")).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ password: expectedPassword }));
          }, 100);
        }
      );
    });

    it("empties status alert", async () => {
      const expectedError = lorem.word();
      mockedHttpHelper.get.mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn((params: IGetParams) => params.onGetSuccess({ data: { externalTypes: [] } } as AxiosResponse)));
      await usingMount(
        <GrabStatusAlertContext>
          <LoginForm model={defaultModelWithEmail} />
        </GrabStatusAlertContext>,
        async wrapper => {
          await setTimeoutPromise(() => {

            statusAlertContext.setStatusAlert({ color: "danger", text: expectedError });

            expect(statusAlertContext.statusAlert).toEqual({ color: "danger", text: expectedError });
            wrapper.find(LoginForm).find("LoginPasswordFormBody").invoke("onPasswordChange")({ target: { name: "password", value: expectedError } });
            wrapper.update();
            expect(statusAlertContext.statusAlert).toEqual({});
          }, 100);
        }
      );
    });
    it("sets passwordError to null", async () => {
      const passwordRequired = lorem.word();
      mockedHttpHelper.get.mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn((params: IGetParams) => params.onGetSuccess({ data: { externalTypes: [] } } as AxiosResponse)));

      await usingMount(
        <GrabStatusAlertContext>
          <LoginForm model={defaultModelWithEmail} />
        </GrabStatusAlertContext>,
        async wrapper => {
          await setTimeoutPromise(() => {
            // trigger passwordError by submitting an empty input and verify passwordError is not null
            wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");

            expect(wrapper.find(LoginForm).find("LoginPasswordFormBody").prop("passwordError")).toEqual("Password is required");
            wrapper.find(LoginForm).find(`input[type="password"]`).simulate("change", { target: { name: "password", value: passwordRequired } });
            wrapper.update();
            expect(wrapper.find(LoginForm).find("LoginPasswordFormBody").prop("passwordError")).toEqual(null);
          }, 100);
        }
      );
    });

  });
```

Please help me any way i can resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: can you also show us the LoginForm component which you are testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem i just gave the element an #id and used it in the find() function

Comment: Can you be more explicit and give a full example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56791503/5670869 you may check this answer, i think that because custom components have multiple layers so id selector is much specific so that `find()` can get the specified layer easily. @DavidLeuliette